# How can I query for text containing Asian-language characters in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, perl, unicode

I have a MySQL table using the UTF-8 character set with a single column called WORDS of type longtext. Values in this column are typed in by users and are a few thousand characters long.

There are two types of rows in this table:

1. In some rows, the WORDS value has been composed by English speakers and contains only characters used in ordinary English writing. (Not all are necessarily ASCII, e.g. the [euro symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm) may appear in some cases.)
2. Other rows have WORDS values written by speakers of Asian languages (Korean, Chinese, Japanese, and possibly others), which include a mix of English words and words in the Asian languages using their native logographic characters (and not, for example, Japanese romaji).

How can I write a query that will return all the rows of type 2 and no rows of type 1? Alternatively, if that's hard, is there a way to query *most* such rows (here it's OK if I miss a few rows of type 2, or include a few false positives of type 1)?

Update: Comments below suggest I might do better to avoid the MySQL query engine altogether, as its regex support for unicode doesn't sound too good. If that's true, I could extract the data into a file (using `mysql -B -e "some SQL here" > extract.txt`) and then use perl or similar on the file. An answer using this method would be OK (but not as good as a native MySQL one!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory you could do this:

1. Find the unicode ranges that you want to test for.
2. Manually encode the start and end into UTF-8.
3. Use the first byte of each of the encoded start and end as a range for a REGEXP.

I believe that the CJK range is far enough removed from things like the euro symbol that the false positives and false negatives would be few or none.

**Edit:** We've now put theory into practice!

**Step 1:**  Choose the character range.  I suggest \u3000-\u9fff; easy to test for, and should give us near-perfect results.

**Step 2:**  Encode into bytes.  [(Wikipedia utf-8 page)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

For our chosen range, utf-8 encoded values will always be 3 bytes, the first of which is 1110xxxx, where xxxx is the most significant four bits of the unicode value.

Thus, we want to mach bytes in the range 11100011 to 11101001, or 0xe3 to 0xe9.

**Step 3:**  Make our regexp using the very handy (and just now discovered by me) UNHEX function.

```
SELECT * FROM `mydata`
WHERE `words` REGEXP CONCAT('[',UNHEX('e3'),'-',UNHEX('e9'),']')
```

Just tried it out.  Works like a charm. :)

Comment: Thanks! http://www.khngai.com/chinese/charmap/tbluni.php?page=0 suggests I need to look for characters with encodings greater than 0x4E00. Unfortunately I don't see how to construct the REGEXP query. I'm just using the ordinary command-line client over an ssh connection to a server, so I don't (I think) have the ability to type in the character 一, which is 0x4E00. A quick google suggests that there is no alternative syntax like "\u4E00". To top it off, I'm not quite sure how to construct a regex for "contains any characters with encoding greater than X". Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, it seems that the mysql regexp engine is lacking something like [\0100-\0177] (that's found pretty much everywhere else).  It's important to note, though, that regexp doesn't know about utf-8 and will do everything bytewise -- hence the (very important) step #2.  As for how to encode the regexp, I'll have to think about that one.

Comment: Well, I got my ssh client to use utf-8 characters like 一 (4E00) and 龥 (9FA5). However a query like `where WORDS REGEXP '[一-龥]'` brings back too much, as I think you predicted. Hm... Also, not sure exactly what step 2 means - how do I "encode the start and end"?

Comment: Ahh... step 2 is the most important!  Each CJK character is encoded in utf-8 as three bytes; REXEP doesn't know about this and just looks at the individual bytes.  Unfortunately, your ssh client is not going to want to let you disassemble individual characters like this.  That's why we need something like \0100 for the regexp -- the \0100 by itself is invalid unicode, but that's what regexp needs to search for.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Let me know if you come up with a way to do it (or maybe someone else will be inspired!)

Comment: @Douglas Cracked it!  Have a look.

Comment: Looking great! Unfortunately that still picks up some English text with weird characters like  , which I think is the invalid Unicode character FOB7 (!?) We have users copying and pasting from Microsoft Word and other strange and noncompliant applications, from which I think these characters come. I did `CONCAT('[',UNHEX('e4'),'-',UNHEX('e9'),']')` which seemed to pick up no false positives. Does this seem right to you? (And thanks!!!)

Comment: e4 - e9 will give you the range \u4000-\u9fff, which should cover most of it.  May be a little more accurate with e3 - e9.

Comment: Excellent, thanks @awm. Editing the answer so the details aren't buried in the comments for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the HEX value of the character. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE <hex code>`

Try it out with `SELECT HEX(column) FROM table`

This might help as well http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-cjk.html

Comment: Thanks! Not sure I understand how to use this. I don't have a single character I want to query - I want to query all characters in the CJK languages.