# Select Rows with Kanji

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called contacts. The name field has both kanji and english names. I would like to be able to query the DB and get only names with Kanji characters in it. It doesn't have to be sorted. It just needed to be kanji names.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051173/how-can-i-query-for-text-containing-asian-language-characters-in-mysql I'm nore sure this is helpful.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?  What properties of Non-English-alphabet names can you use to solve this problem?

Comment: @JungsuHeo Your link works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from <table_name> where name like 'kanji'
```

Comment: hello, `kanji` is Chinese character name. so OP is looking for how to search certain character set.